# Linking a function to a timer with Qt

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, timer, signals

I have a function whose declaration is above:

```
double image_function(double SUM, double AVR, double &Value)
```

I have read that SIGNALS and SLOTS must have the same arguments, how is it possible to adjust that condition when applyinh a timer to my function as follow:

```
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(image_function()));
timer->start(0);
```

Comment: What parameters do you expect your `image_function` to be called with on `timeout()`? What shall happen with the return value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not possible. Your function needs 3 parameters, you *have* to give them. How could the timer know anything about your function's parameters?

Create a slot function (without any parameters) for the timer's timeout. From there call the `image_function` with parameters you want.

Let's say your class is a mainwindow. You need to declare the slot for the QTimer's timeout signal:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ...

private slots:
    void timer_image_function();

};
```

Then in the .cpp, you somewhere create a QTimer and connect its signal to this new slot:

```
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(timer_image_function()));
timer->start(0);
```

And of course, you need to implement the slot function, which actually calls the `image_function`:

```
void MainWindow::timer_image_function()
{
    double result = image_function(SUM, AVR, Value);
}
```

Comment: timeout belongs to which classname? It's not recognized when creating a new slot function with it

Comment: It says that it cannot be accessed. It's protected!